# WolframAlfa/Mathematica how to find function local maximum on interval

Tags: functions, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I have a polynomial function and i want to find it's minimum and maximum on a the interval [0, 5] with Wolfram Alphaa but i forgot the proper input.

I recall it went something like so: $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + n = 0$ maximum on interval $[0, 5]$, however now it just gives the output of my input and no result.

Comment: It seems it's no longer possible i would have to use the interactive graph but cant use that gives an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working for me (minimize works as well):

"maximize x^4+x^3+x^2+x^1+n on [0,5]"

[Here is the output.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20x%5E4%2bx%5E3%2bx%5E2%2bx%5E1%2bn%20on%20%5B0,5%5D)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate worked like a charm.